Elastic Agent how to ingest AWS Glue metrics
I'm running Elastic Agent (v8.12.2) on an AWS EC2 instance collecting cloudwatch metrics.
I'm using AWS integration, and understand that Glue's metrics is available under cloudwatch metrics, hence I put the below metrics definitions.

(I wasn't sure if the namespace should be Glue or AWS/Glue, so I put both) But the metrics are not ingested.
I also tried just putting the - namespace: AWS/Glue and - namespace: Glue alone. Also does not work. Any idea I can I ingest them?

Did not have any data ingested because there has been no glue jobs started after I updated the cloudwatch metricset to collect.
Additional:
Putting the 2 namespaces below will work. There are metrics under both namespaces.
- namespace: AWS/Glue
- namespace: Glue
